# Cron jobbin' a python script: stops halfway through

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to cronjob my python script. I set it up through cPanel and my python script generates an html file like it's supposed to, so I know the command it correct (just "python /path" right?)

HOWEVER, my generated html stops halfway through (right after the second f.write(), when my for loop should start).

When I execute this script locally, I get no problems, what gives?

```
from SearchPhone import SearchPhone

phones = ["Iphone 3", "Iphone 4", "Iphone 5","Galaxy s3", "Galaxy s2", "LG Lucid", "LG Esteem", "HTC One S", "Droid 4",
          "Droid RAZR MAXX", "HTC EVO", "Galaxy Nexus", "LG Optimus 2", "LG Ignite",
          "Galaxy Note", "HTC Amaze", "HTC Rezound", "HTC Vivid", "HTC Rhyme", "Motorola Photon",
          "Motorola Milestone", "myTouch slide", "HTC Status", "Droid 3", "HTC Evo 3d", "HTC Wildfire",
          "LG Optimus 3d", "HTC ThunderBolt", "Incredible 2", "Kyocera Echo", "Galaxy S 4g",
          "HTC Inspire", "LG Optimus 2x", "Samsung Gem", "HTC Evo Shift", "Nexus S", "LG Axis", "Droid 2",
          "G2", "Droid x", "Droid Incredible" 
          ]

f = open('celly.html','w')


f.write("""<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Celly Blue Book</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
""")

#table
f.write('<table width="100%" border="1">')
for x in phones:
    y = SearchPhone(x)
    f.write( "\t<tr>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[0]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[1]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[2]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[3]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t\t<td>" + str(y[4]) + "</td>")
    f.write( "\t</tr>"

f.write('</table>')

f.close()
```

Comment: Dunno the answer, but `str.format`, `str.join`, and for loops are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

1. Last  line in your for loop has syntax error :

   `f.write( "\t</tr>"`
2. You may not have write permissions on your production server .
   Try this once.

`f = open('/tmp/celly.html','w')`

if this works, then its a write permission problem.
Check permissions of your
`celly.html` file in current folder. It should be writable.

Comment: You're right! my celly.html was set at 644.  What should it be?

Comment: hmm, even at 777 celly.html remains truncated.  Did I misinterpret your answer?

Comment: Ahhh thanks.  (Un)fortunately I had fixed that server-side (but I remain with half-a-script).

Comment: Oh, excuse me, is it an issue that it is being saved in the tmp folder? Does THAT mean I don't have write permissions??

Comment: Because it is being saved there.